# Problem when bidi & hyperref packages are used with custom document class (XeLaTeX)

Tags: xetex, hyperref, documentclass-writing, bidi

There is a problem when bidi & hyperref packages are used together and custom document style is used. For example:

```
\documentclass[unicode]{myreport}

\usepackage{xltxtra}

\author{Author}
\title{Title}

\usepackage[pagebackref=true, xetex, unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bidi}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Test

\end{document}
```

`myreport` class is the exact copy of standard `report` class (nothing is changed). Problem is in `\maketitle` command. Result:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\@ifnextchar #1#2#3->\let \reserved@d =#1
                                         \def \reserved@a {#2}\def \reserved...
l.14
```

This error doesn't occur when:

1. `hyperref` package isn't used, or
2. standard `report` class is uded, or
3. `\maketitle` command isn't used

I can't find any information about such behavior neither in bidi nor in hyperref documentation, nor in google.

I see that `bidi` package uses command `\@ifclassloaded` and plugs files like `report-xetex-bidi.def`. Maybe such file should be created for custom docclass. But I saw this file and didn't find anything 'special' in it.

Bidi package is needed, since document will be multilingual with polyglossia and with some text in Arabic (and maybe other) language.

What can be done in this situation?

Comment: I suspect that such behavior started since the last update, as I worked someway a week before.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There *is* something special in `report-xetex-bidi.def`: some commands, in particular `\maketitle` are redefined to cope with bidirectional input. A recommended practice is to `\LoadClass{report}` and do the desired modifications after this, instead of writing a class from scratch.

Comment: Yes, `\maketitle` is redefined, but I don't see anything special in the redefined `\maketitle`. I see, that, if I don't use RTL characters in title page, all should work without redefinition.

Comment: Well, I *do* see special things in the redefined `\maketitle` which are important for *allowing* RTL in the title.

Comment: This doesn't explain why hyperref package is involved.

Comment: Yes, using of standard class is commonly good, but in my case almost all code will be changed, including maketitle, abstract, chapter, section, appendix, thebibliography and so on. I think that using of original class isn't efficient.

Answer (score 2):

I can not reproduce the problem if I create myreport.cls as:

```
\LoadClass{report}

\endinput
```

However if your `myreport.cls` is verbatim copy of `report.cls`, then the error you described follows. The best is to use `\LoadClass` and then doing your redefinitions as user @egreg explained. There are few changes to `\maketitle` in `report-xetex.def`. If you study the code clearly it is some changes with respect to footnote rule (`\right@footnote`, `\left@footnote`, and `\textwidth@footnote`) and some footnote commands (`\footnote`, `\LTRfootnote`, `\RTLfootnote`, `\thanks`, `\LTRthanks`, and `\RTLthanks`). Why this error happens with `hyperref` and why this is related to `hyperref` package? If you look at the `hyperref` package, there are some redefinitions of `\maketitle`, and the file `hyperref-xetex-bidi.def` redefines those changes of `\maketitle` that `hyperref` does to give you correct hyperlinks in RTL mode. First you load `myreport.cls`, so there is obviously a definition of `\maketitle`, then when you load `hyperref`, it does `\let\HyOrg@maketitle\maketitle` and then makes some changes to the `\maketitle` command; later you load `bidi` and because `bidi` needs to do some modification to `hyperref`, it also does `\let\HyOrg@maketitle\maketitle` and also some modifications to `\maketitle`, so obviously unless there is a redefinition of `\maketitle` before loading `hyperref-xetex-bidi.def`, you get a "TeX capacity exceeded" error.

**Conclusion:** As you can guess, things get complex and complicated so it is best to use `\LoadClass` and let the `bidi` package take care of issues automatically.

Comment: This appears to be similar to the problem with `amsart` that was reported [here](http://www.tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2011-September/021318.html) and subsequently fixed.  But I guess there is no easy way to preempt the problem for every document class.