# clv3 and hyperref conflict TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]

Tags: xetex, hyperref, documentclass-writing, bidi

I have a problem when using the below code I got an error

> TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. \begin

I searched and I found another question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61063/problem-when-bidi-hyperref-packages-are-used-with-custom-document-class-xelat?rq=1). It is a similar issue but did not solve my problem.

Code:

```latex
\documentclass{clv3}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[dvipsnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,citecolor=darkblue, linkcolor=darkblue, urlcolor=darkblue}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}
\usepackage{tipa}
\input{preamble_tikz.tex}
\input{figures/pgfplot_configurations.tex}

\let\numdef\relax%@@@Fix conflict with @polyglossia
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\setmainfont[Scale=0.925]{heuristica}
\usepackage{bidipoem}
\newcommand*\samethanks[1][\value{footnote}]{\footnotemark[#1]}
\begin{document}



\author{author1}\thanks{thank1}}
\affil{aff1}
%%%
\author{author2\thanks{thank2}%
\thanks{thank3}}
\affil{aff2}
%%%
\author{author3\thanks{thank3}%
\samethanks[3]}
\affil{aff3}
%%%
\author{author4\thanks{thank4}%
\samethanks[3]}
\affil{aff4}%%%%
%%%%%%%
\author{author5\thanks{thank5}%
\samethanks[5]}
\affil{aff5}

\title{XYX}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

The problem could be fixed in the below cases

1. Remove `\usepackage{hyperref}` but the links will not work.
2. Remove `\maketitle` command.

After some searching, I found it could be a conflict because `hyperref` redefined `\maketitle` and `bidi` does the same. But I can't figure out how to fix that.

[image]

Comment: Where can the `clv3` class be downloaded?

Comment: http://cljournal.org/style.html?fbclid=IwAR0KqL4ssoypcgxxeEAyssHL_ZcVxZoifOeIuxU3slRbKLzxt9-U7mWVu0w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `bidi` that gets confused with the nonstandard definition of `\maketitle`.

If you don't plan to use Arabic in the header, you can fix the issue by saving and restoring the meaning of `\maketitle` (actually the copy maintained by `hyperref`).

```latex
\documentclass{clv3}
%\documentclass{article}

\let\numdef\relax

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[dvipsnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{bidipoem}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\let\clvHyOrg@maketitle\HyOrg@maketitle
\makeatother

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,citecolor=darkblue, linkcolor=darkblue, urlcolor=darkblue}

%\input{preamble_tikz.tex}
%\input{figures/pgfplot_configurations.tex}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\setmainfont[Scale=0.925]{heuristica}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\let\HyOrg@maketitle\clvHyOrg@maketitle}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\title{XYZ}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

I have also reorganized the preamble to be more consistent.

Comment: I am using Arabic and Poem in my code. What do you recommend?

Comment: @MoustafaMahmoud Also in the title?

Comment: No inside the text only the title doesn’t contain Arabic

Comment: @MoustafaMahmoud Then you shouldn't worry; the “fix” just affects the data needed for `\maketitle`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will try it and feedback soon

Comment: I updated the code but it seems there is another issue happened. The thanks text for the last author before the \maketitle go outside the margin

Comment: I updated the code